# How can I make sure a string contains at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one punctuation character?

Tags: shell, posix, pattern-matching

This is what I'm using now to get the job done:

```
#!/bin/sh --

string='Aa1!z'

if ! printf '%s\n' "$string" | LC_ALL=C grep -q '[[:upper:]]' || \
   ! printf '%s\n' "$string" | LC_ALL=C grep -q '[[:lower:]]' || \
   ! printf '%s\n' "$string" | LC_ALL=C grep -q '[[:digit:]]' || \
   ! printf '%s\n' "$string" | LC_ALL=C grep -q '[[:punct:]]'; then
  printf '%s\n' 'String does not meet your requirements'
else
  printf '%s\n' 'String meets your requirements'
fi
```

This is extermely inefficent and verbose. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Self-documenting code is a virtue; I might have written it positively (does the string have an upper and a lower and ...) just to make it quicker to read through the logic.  What does "better" mean to you, here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I just don't like I had to make four calls to grep

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: People who put arbitrary restrictions on passwords are the worst. You're literally telling hackers what characters they should expect in a password.

Comment: @TomášZato  On the other side of the argument, you are also making sure that users can’t enter a very simple password.  In other words, you are increasing the average password entropy.

Comment: @dalearn It's still solving the wrong problem.  When you solve the wrong problem, that's a hack.  By restricting what people can enter, you in fact *decrease* the entropy - the average only goes up because many people would otherwise choose weak passwords.  You don't need to enforce this specific pattern to disallow weak passwords, however.

Comment: @dalearn I tend to get annoyed when a silly script tells me that my 40 letter passphrase is too simple but an 8 letter one that I won't remember is strong enough.

Comment: You might want to take a look at official recommendations from, e.g., [NIST](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#memsecret). But questions about this are probably better asked on [security.se] (though search there first, as they already have a bunch)

Comment: @TomášZato Note that similar tests could be done on strings that are _not_ passwords. In fact, in many cases, it may be easier to read a series of _simple_ regular expressions or globbing patterns than one single monster pattern trying to do too many assertions at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With one call to `awk` and without pipe:

```
#! /bin/sh -
string='whatever'

has_char_of_each_class() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -- '
    BEGIN {
      for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++)
        if (ARGV[1] !~ "[[:" ARGV[i] ":]]") exit 1
    }' "$@"
}

if has_char_of_each_class "$string" lower upper digit punct; then
  echo OK
else
  echo not OK
fi
```

That's POSIX but note that `mawk` doesn't support POSIX character classes yet. The `--` is not needed with POSIX compliant `awk`s but would be in older versions of busybox `awk` (which would choke on values of `$string`  that start with `-`).

A variant of that function using a `case` shell construct:

```
has_char_of_each_class() {
  input=$1; shift
  for class do
    case $input in
      (*[[:$class:]]*) ;;
      (*) return 1;;
    esac
  done
}
```

Note however that changing the locale for the shell in the middle of a script doesn't work with all `sh` implementations (so you'd need the script to be called in the C locale already if you want the input to be considered as being encoded in the C locale charset and the character classes to match only the ones specified by POSIX).

Answer (score 7):

With flexible `awk` pattern matching:

```
if [[ $(echo "$string" | awk '/[a-z]/ && /[A-Z]/ && /[0-9]/ && /[[:punct:]]/') ]]; then  
    echo "String meets your requirements"
else 
    echo "String does not meet your requirements"
fi
```

Comment: +1, but the OP's code has a `/bin/sh` shebang line and you're using a bashism by way of `[[`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I seem to be having issues making this work properly, even if I change the interpreter to bash; I get the output "String does not meet your requirements" whether the string does or does not meet my requirements

Comment: @HaroldFischer, are you using `mawk`? Refer Stephane's note around `mawk` in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553043/21233)

Comment: If you're going to upgrade to Bash, might as well just use the _built-in_ regex matching of `[[` ...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Is there any way this can be done with `-v var="$string"` instead of using `echo` or `printf`? Thought you might know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

The following script is longer than your code, but shows how you could test a string against a list of patterns.  The code detects whether the string matches all patterns or not and prints out a result.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

string=TestString1

failed=false

for pattern in '*[[:upper:]]*' '*[[:lower:]]*' '*[[:digit:]]*' '*[[:punct:]]*'
do
    case $string in
        $pattern) ;;
        *)
            failed=true
            break
    esac
done

if "$failed"; then
    printf '"%s" does not meet the requirements\n' "$string"
else
    printf '"%s" is ok\n' "$string"
fi
```

The `case ... esac` compound command is the POSIX way to test a string against a set of globbing patterns.  The variable `$pattern` is used unquoted in the test, so that the match is not done as a string comparison. If the string does not match the given pattern, then it will match `*`, and the loop is exited after setting `failed` to `true`.

Running this would yield

```
$ sh script.sh
"TestString1" does not meet the requirements
```

You could tuck the testing away in a function like so (the code tests a number of strings in a loop, calling the function):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

test_string () {
    for pattern in '*[[:upper:]]*' '*[[:lower:]]*' '*[[:digit:]]*' '*[[:punct:]]*'
    do
        case $1 in ($pattern) ;; (*) return 1; esac
    done
}

for string in TestString1 Test.String2 TestString-3; do
    if ! test_string "$string"; then
        printf '"%s" does not meet the requirements\n' "$string"
    else
        printf '"%s" is ok\n' "$string"
    fi
done
```

If you want to set `LC_ALL=C` locally in the function, write it as

```sh
test_string () (
    LC_ALL=C

    for pattern in '*[[:upper:]]*' '*[[:lower:]]*' '*[[:digit:]]*' '*[[:punct:]]*'
    do
        case $1 in ($pattern) ;; (*) return 1; esac
    done
)
```

Note that the body of the function now is in a sub-shell. Setting `LC_ALL=C` will therefore not affect the value of this variable in the calling environment.

Get the shell function to take the patterns as arguments too, and you basically get [Stéphane Chazelas' answer (the variant)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553043/116858).

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by RomanPerekhrest, but with some minor refinements to do away with the pipeline and command substitution:

```
if awk '/[[:lower:]]/ && /[[:upper:]]/ && /[[:digit:]]/ && /[[:punct:]]/ {exit 1}' <<< "$string" ; then
  echo "did not match all requirements"
else
  echo "looks good to me"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

This is RomanPerekhrest's answer rewritten to work with mawk:

```
#!/bin/sh --

string='Aa1!z'

if printf '%s\n' "$string" | LC_ALL=C awk '/[a-z]/ && /[A-Z]/ && /[0-9]/ && /[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]/ {exit 1}'; then
  printf '%s\n' 'String does not meet your requirements'
else
  printf '%s\n' 'String meets your requirements'
fi
```

It also borrows from bxm's answer by using awk's exit code instead of checking whether's awk's output is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing shamelessly from @HaroldFischer @bxm and @RomanPerekhrest for a pure `awk` solution

```
awk -v test="does not meet" '/[a-z]/ && /[A-Z]/ && /[0-9]/ && /[[:punct:]]/ {test="meets"}
    END {print "String "test" your requirements"}' <<<"Aa&0"
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, since no other answers mention PCRE. A limitation [of BRE/ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) is that you cannot trivially¹ implement a logical *and* for the equivalent logical "or" in *alternation* with `|`.

[PCRE patterns](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html) let you create "and" conditions using zero-width assertions: look-ahead or look-behind. These "consume" no characters, but restrict matching before or after patterns. There are many ways to use these, putting look-aheads up front makes sense here:

```
LC_ALL=C pcregrep -q '(?=.*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[[:lower:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]]).{4,}'
```

The PCRE applies 4 "preconditions" to the input before applying the match `.{4,}` (4 or more characters, feel free to make it larger ;-). One point to note is that "`(?=[[:upper:]])`" will only inspect a single character, so each condition is preceded with "`.*`" so the entire input is checked. `pcregrep` also supports a locale via `--locale=C`.

Since the "P" in PCRE stands for `perl`:

```
perl -wln -e \
  '/(?=.*[[:upper:]])(?=.*[[:lower:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])(?=.*[[:punct:]]).{4,}/ && exit 0; exit 1;'
```

does the same thing for a *single line of input* (it's not a general replacement for "`pcregrep -q`").

A head-spinning superset of this type of problem can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator

---

¹
You *could* expand an ERE to emulate "and" by permutations:

```
[[:lower:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:digit:]].*[[:punct:]]|
[[:lower:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:punct:]].*[[:digit:]]|
[[:lower:]].*[[:digit:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:punct:]]| ... 20 more lines ...
[[:punct:]].*[[:digit:]].*[[:upper:]].*[[:lower:]]
```

Definitely not going to help with being "inefficent and verbose".

Answer (score 0):

Now if `bash` were an option:
You could enable [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and combine the `@(` and `!(` sub-patterns to construct the glob `@(!(*[[:upper:]]*)|!(*[[:lower:]]*)|!(*[[:punct:]]*)|!(*[[:digit:]]*))` to compare against

```bsh
$ shopt -s extglob
$ arr=( '!(*'{'[[:upper:]]','[[:lower:]]','[[:punct:]]','[[:digit:]]'}'*)' )
$ pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '@(%s)' "${arr[*]}")
$ printf "$pattern\n"
@(!(*[[:upper:]]*)|!(*[[:lower:]]*)|!(*[[:punct:]]*)|!(*[[:digit:]]*))
$ [[ 'Aa3,' = $pattern ]] && echo yes
$ [[ 'Aa3' = $pattern ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ 'Aa,' = $pattern ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ 'A3,' = $pattern ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ 'a3,' = $pattern ]] && echo yes
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Below creates a random password with the requested.
You can make the password longer by replacing `head -c 12` with a larger value.

```bash
while true
do
  A=$(head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9.\'\"$,_! | head -c 12 ; echo '')

  [[ ${A} =~ [A-Z] && ${A} =~ [a-z] && ${A} =~ [0-9] && ${A} =~ [.\'\"$,_!] ]] && break

done
```